# Trying to add a canvas to a WPF ElementHost in Windows Forms App?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I'm trying to get the ability to use the touch screen on a windows tablet in my application.  All the examples I've seen use system.windows.Input and get touch points from a WPF canvas.  My app is a winforms app and I don't have the time (deadline this week) to convert the app, so I thought to try the elementhost method, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

I've added an elementhost to my form, and then I wanted to create a canvas and add it...but it looks like the elementhost will only hold windows forms controls?!?

```
System.Windows.Controls.Canvas touchcanvas = new System.Windows.Controls.Canvas();
elementHost1.Controls.Add(touchcanvas);
```

It gives me an error on the controls.add because touchcanvas is not a valid windows forms control.

How can I add a WPF canvas to the elementhost and be able to raise it's events? such as touch events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to use `Child` property of `ElementHost`.

```
elementHost1.Child = touchcanvas;
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked...but at this point how do I interact with the child?  I'm trying to implement this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.touch%28v=vs.100%29.aspx in a windows form application. I can't seem to get e.GetTouchPoints to recognize the canvas.  After adding it as a child, how do I get touch to work?

Comment: Am sorry, I'm not used to it. Did you try as the msdn sample? What does `e.GetTouchPoints` returns?

Comment: Its used in an iterative loop for all touchpoints. foreach (TouchPoint _touchpoint in e.GetTouchPoints(touchcanvas));